# vba to copy and paste but skips few rows

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm new to this forum. and I have some problem.

I want to copy a list from sheet "Import Data" to sheet "June" but each list I want to skip few rows.

I've come out with some code but it didn't work. When I run the code individually, it skips the second For loop.

please help me.

```
Sub copypasteskip()

Dim sheet1 As Variant
Dim sheet2 As Variant
Dim endnumber As Integer
Dim finalrow As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer


Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("June")
Set sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportData")

endnumber = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
finalrow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row


For r = 11 To endnumber 'the list should paste starts at rows 11, cells "A"
        
        
        For i = 14 To finalrow 'the list need to be copy starts at rows 14,cells "D"
        
   
                sheet2.Cells(i, "D").End(xlDown).Copy
                sheet1.Cells(r, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
          
        
        Next i
        
       r = r + 7 'need to skips 7 rows for each list
    
Next r

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your second For loop doesn’t run that means that the value of finalrow is less than 11. Try using the locals Windows or hovering your mouse over the name to see its value. You could also insert a `debug.print(finalrow)`
just before the first loop.

```
Sub copypasteskip()

    Dim sheet1 As Variant
    Dim sheet2 As Variant
    Dim endnumber As Integer
    Dim finalrow As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    
    
    Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("June")
    Set sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportData")
    
    endnumber = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    finalrow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    For r = 11 To endnumber Step 7 'the list should paste starts at rows 11, column 1
            
            
            For i = 14 To finalrow 'the list need to be copy starts at rows 14,column 4
            
      
                    sheet1.Cells(r, 1) = sheet2.Cells(i, 4)
              
            
            Next i
            
        
    Next r
    
    End sub
```

Comment: yes. I run the code with immediate watch and do the debug.print(finalrow) and i get value 7. but how did it get 7? and my endnumber, I get 6. I'm sorry I am new to vba. how to change this?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t look very closely before. You’re also using Cells() incorrectly. Unlike Range () you can’t use letters in Cells. For example change Cells(Rows.Count, “A”) to Cells(Rows.Count, 1)  Do this for each instance of Cells() and that should fix it. Note I’m not my computer so I can’t test anything.

Comment: What is it you’re actually trying to do?

Comment: Actually I want to copy a list from sheet "Import Data" to "June" sheet. There is 20 ID list on "Import Data" sheet and I want to copy and paste it to "June" sheet but skips 7 rows for each id.